# Port Forwarding, and Python Sockets

Tags: networking, router, portforwarding

Alright so I have a few questions, I have a D - link 2650u router in my house let's start with that

now I wrote a TCP server in Python that binds itself to my private IP address and to port 5000, ( My **private IP** address is 10.0.0.4), For example let's say my **public IP** address is 76.123.24.21. Now, my TCP server works fine within the LAN and within the private IP addresses, However if I want other people to be able to send packets to me and my server to receive them from outside the LAN I need to open port 5000 and forward it, e.g, enter to my router's NAT port forwarding table and define that all packets received on port 5000 would be forwarded to my **private ip** address which is 10.0.0.4.
So my first question is this, If I forward port 5000 to 10.0.04 this means that every packet sent to 76.123.24.21:5000 would be received in my TCP server that is binded on port 5000, correct? ( Of course if the packet is sent from a TCP socket )

Now my second question is, How do I forward ports on my router..... I have a **D - link DSL 2650u** router, and whenever I login to it's webpage, and connect with the correct username and password, All the options it shows me are:

Device Info
   Diagnostics
   Management

and nothing regarding advanced settings or NAT to forward ports......

Please help me with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yea. Your are right. Every packet with TCP destination port equals to 5000 will be forwarded to 10.0.0.4 . Inside port number and outside port number could be the same or difference, router doesn't care.
2. Port Forwarding is known as "Virtual Server" in D-Link literature. You can configure port forwarding under "Advanced Setup" in "NAT - Virtual Servers".

Any client PC in the DMZ will be exposed to various types of security risks. So if your application just uses a port, only use port forwarding.

Comment: Thanks man, I've managed accessing the port opening section yet it doesn't seem to work no clue why... I've asked my router manufacture forum for support and if it doesn't work I'll post it over here I didn't see the advanced settings because I was viewing it as a user apparently anyways thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. This is your router's user manual: [link](http://www.enativ.com/download/DSL-2650.pdf). Yea, it seems you have not privileged access to your router. Have you tested reset password yet?

Answer (score 0):

Since TCP server in behind a NAT device, which means TCP client outside a NAT device need to initialize a socket connection. I suggest you open a DMZ host in your router but a port forwarding.

It should be in the management. Look for DMZ settings.

Comment: Alright then, so if I want to bind all packets sent to port 5000 sent to my private ip which is 10.0.0.4, What do I do?

Comment: @user3687265 If you have to use port forwarding, then you should bind your TCP server with other ports, like 4000. Then add a forwarding rule like 'protocol:TCP, service port:5000, internal port:4000'. And you have to trigger this rule so that TCP SYN packet could come inside.

Comment: are you sure....? Doesnt it work this way?, lets say I bind port 80 to My private IP then when accessing my public ip on port 80 the packet is forwarded to my private ip...?

Comment: @user3687265 I mean port(let's say portA) to your private IP(10.0.0.4) must be different from port(let's say portB) to your public IP(76.123.24.21). You can set portA to 80. And then you need to set portB to 5000 in port forwarding settings in the router.Thus traffic to portB on public IP will be forwarded to portA on private IP. That's how port forwarding works.

Comment: That's just incorrect.... It doesn't have to be... PAT / NAT does it with sent info with the NAT forwarding table, however port forwarding is for incoming information isn't it? In any place I read when I forward a port, It just sends from PublicIP:PortA to PrivateIP:PortA....
I know that you can set it to be from PublicIP:PortA to PrivateIP:PortB but it doesnt have to be this way.... i've managed to find access to my port forward UCP yet it seems that I cant even open the port

Comment: All packet not matching in forwarding table will forward to DMZ host. It means an attacker outside of your network can access most of open ports of the host. So DMZ is not preferable solution.